# Setting environment to use PyOpenColorIO in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pipenv

In my notebook I would like to use PyOpenColorIO. I have installed that library via `brew install opencolorio` and I have confirmed that I can use it from within my `pipenv`-created virtual environment (both from the REPL as well as from a script) after `source`-ing the [environment configuration](https://opencolorio.org/old/installation.html#quick-environment-configuration) that ships with the library.

However, I am unable to set up this environment from within my notebook and thus cannot use the library from there - `import PyOpenColorIO as OCIO` always throws `No module named 'PyOpenColorIO'`.

Things I've tried so far and their results:

- set each variable `export`ed from the shell file with `%env` or `%setenv` before importing OCIO, both using quotes and without quotes

  - variables are set when checking with `%env`, but `${PATH}` and Co are not substituted
- set each variable with `os.environ["VARNAME"]` before importing OCIO

  - same as above
- run `!source /usr/local/share/ocio/setup_ocio.sh` at the beginning of the notebook

  - no change in `%env` at all

It seems to me that there should be a way of setting up the environment as part of the kernel startup, *before* any cells are executed. However I haven't been able to find such an option. Does it exist? Or is there any other way to get OCIO to work in a notebook using a virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

After digging around some more, I found a solution that works: [pipenv can automatically load .env files](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#automatic-loading-of-env).

This sets the variables before they are needed to load the module.